Developer Powershell in Visual Studio ignores special char in user variables
If I try to run dotnet build from Powershell inside Visual Studio I get and error that access to the path is denied.

If I run the same command in Powershell outside Visual Sudio the command works normally.

The issue seems to be that Powershell ignores a special character in my useraname and REPLACES š with s.
If I print out env variables I can see the difference.
Visual Studio Powershell

Powershell

I tried to run the same powershell that is specified in VS developer console profile, but there is always a difference between the one run by Visual Studio or not.

How to force Visual Studio to respect my ENV VARs as they are ?
I cannot change my user folder (company computer with limitations).
EDIT:
I found out that the problem is not with the PowerShell, but rather Developer PowerShell.
The arguments when the Powershell is run in Visual Studio are like that:
-NoExit -Command "& { Import-Module """$env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell -SkipAutomaticLocation -SetDefaultWindowTitle -InstallPath $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\..\}"
I enabled the Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support as I saw it here and this  seems to fix the issue with the Developer Powershell.

I need to test it more thoroughtly, because it may come with some caveats.

Perhaps How to config visual studio to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for all projects? will help?

Adding
charset = utf-8```
to `.editorconfig` didn't help.

Or CLI console output uses UTF-8 ?
